# DayOfTheYear in delphi

Tags: delphi, date

When I use the DayOfTheyear function I obtain the error
[Error] Unit1.pas(85): Undeclared identifier: 'DayOfTheyear'
Should I include any unit?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI, if you know the function name, you can look it up in the help, which mentions the unit to include. (I'm not saying you're wrong to ask here: if you didn't realise it would help to look there, asking is perfectly sensible.)

Comment: Personally, I don't think that StackOverflow is a good place to reproduce the entire contents of "Hitting F1 to find the context-sensitive-help for an RTL function" thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add `DateUtils` to your `uses` clause.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Delphi 5 there is no unit to access these date/time functions as DateUtils.dcu didn't appear until D6 and SysUtils is pretty limited which is why you are getting 'Undeclared Identifier'.  Unfortunately, you can't copy the utilites from another version to D5 as Delphi won't work with it.